# Play video from an intermediate point

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, rtmp

I am in the middle of an application that has a module to play videos from a directory on the same web-server. Everything is fine, except for the point that, while video is streaming, if I try to drag the player tip to an intermediate point, it either drags back to where it was(in flex player) or keeps loading un-till the video actually approaches that point(in case of jw-player or html5 player) or does nothing(in some other online players available). My client wants to be able to play or start buffering from any desirable point. I read something about RTMP to be used for such thing, but wasnt able to find a direct guide over how to do it.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that your video is streaming?  Or is it "load as needed"?  You can only jump immediately to certain points if you have a streaming server in use; such as Flash Media Server or Red5.  Any standard HTTP Server can't jump directly to the middle of a video; it will have to load all the bytes between the current point and the point you want to jump to.

Comment: What is the container format for the video files? Is is mp4?

Comment: @szatmary: as of now the format is flv, but there is no restriction over the format. I can ask my client to convert videos in any format you advise.

Comment: @Reboog711 : You are right. The video plays but it is not able to jump over any middle point. Can you please guide me in a direction over how to achieve this?

Comment: @Vijit Use a media server, such as the open source Red5 or Adobe's Flash Media Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about being able to load a video file from x seconds in to the video, you should look into http pseudo-streaming. Here's a link to the jwplayer page about it: [jwplayer pseudo-streaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got some idea, but I am having trouble installing it on my server. Any help? I have a vps hosting account, with access to whm on cent os.